# ¿Por qué es necesario tener 5 votos positivos en una etiqueta para poder proponer un sinónimo de etiqueta?

Tags: soporte, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Traduciendo los privilegios del sitio me tope con la siguiente regla:

> Users with this privilege and a total answer score (total upvotes
>   minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag
>   synonyms. Users with a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can
>   vote for tag synonyms.

Traducción:

> Usuarios con este privilegio y un puntaje total de respuestas(votos
>   positivos menos votos negativos) de 5 o más en la etiqueta, pueden
>   sugerir sinónimos de etiquetas. Usuarios con un puntaje total de
>   repuestas de 5 o más en la etiqueta, pueden votar por sinónimos de
>   etiquetas.

Supongo que es debido a que los usuarios experimentados en cada etiqueta son los que deben proponer sinónimos de etiquetas, pero me he dado cuenta que no se lo hace, por ejemplo se creo la etiqueta **[node](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node)**, que hace referencia a **[nodejs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs)**, claro que se podría cambiar la etiqueta y dejar que se elimine después de un tiempo de no tener preguntas, pero la idea de los sinónimos de etiqueta es arreglar etiquetas incorrectas sustituyéndolas con las etiquetas correctas, para de esa manera tener preguntas un poco más "limpias" de parte de los nuevos usuarios.

Quise proponer ese sinónimo pero no pude hacerlo por que no tengo el puntaje requerido en la etiqueta.

Answer (score 6):

Requerir que tenga 5 puntos es una muy buena garantía de que sea un usuario experimentado, que sepa de qué se trata el tema, quien esté proponiendo un sinónimo que podría implementarse. Es una forma de reasegurarse que sea la opinión formada de un usuario que al menos sabe algo del tema en cuestión, y pueda tomar una decisión consciente acerca de las preguntas que se están etiquetando mal frecuentemente o de los casos en los que se están utilizando múltiples etiquetas para un mismo tema. Hay que considerar que un sinónimo de etiqueta puede tener un impacto enorme en el sitio, sobre todo si se crea un sinónimo incorrecto. Una forma eficiente de reaseguro es totalmente necesaria. Como todo filtro, puede fallar, pero teniendo en cuenta el sistema de reputación de Stack Overflow, en mi opinión es una estrategia bastante buena.

Asimismo, se necesita el voto de **4** usuarios para generar el sinónimo: uno de los filtros más altos, que denota el gran efecto que puede tener.

Imaginemos un absurdo: ¿qué pasaría si se llegase a aprobar a [c++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) como sinónimo de [c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)? El autor de una pregunta no necesariamente vería que se cambió la etiqueta. Un editor podría no entender por qué no puede reetiquetarla. Y mientras tanto, los comentarios que se les ocurran.

Es cierto que, como el sitio tiene menos de 1 año, hay algunas etiquetas que no tienen la suficiente cantidad de preguntas como para tener el puntaje necesario (o que haya suficientes usuarios para votar). Pero al mismo tiempo, al haber pocas preguntas de algunas etiquetas, el impacto quizás no es tan alto, y es fácil de corregir, ya sea:

1. Editando esas preguntas manualmente.
2. Proponiendo el sinónimo en meta para que la comunidad la discuta y, si están de acuerdo, que un moderador genere el sinónimo.

A favor, sólo hace falta 1250 puntos de experiencia para proponer un sinónimo (versus los 2500 necesarios en sitios ya graduados -no beta).

Sin embargo, dicho esto, lo más probable es que por el momento no haya suficientes usuarios para votar por un sinónimo que propongas. Para [nodejs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs), actualmente sólo hay [8 usuarios que podrían votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/nodejs/topusers).

Comment: Buena respuesta, estoy de acuerdo en que los usuarios experimentados sean los que propongan los sinónimos, pero sería bueno que en la beta algunos usuarios también puedan hacerlo, orientado a mejorar el sitio con un correcto etiquetado, aunque como dices, sería de proponerlo a la comunidad para que un moderador genere el sinónimo.

Comment: @JuanPinzón sin duda, creo que más que bajar los límites, conviene fomentar las discusiones abiertas durante el beta.Y no sólo como reaseguro, sino también para que sea visible cómo vamos construyendo el sitio.

Comment: Me pregunto por qué no votaron a favor esos 8 usuarios.

Comment: @ArtEze Nadie propuso el sinónimo hasta ahora.