# ¿Cuáles son los pasos a seguir en la creación de un sinónimo de etiqueta?

Tags: soporte, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Hay dos etiquetas y considero que una debería ser sinónimo de la otra. Revisé que no sean pocas (sería demasiado ruido reetiquetar a mano), o creo que es un típico caso reincidente, de esas etiquetas que siempre vuelven a aparecer.

Tengo algunas dudas de los pasos a seguir:

- Mi primer paso debería ser llevar el tema a Meta, con [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n),
  [etiquetas](/questions/tagged/etiquetas) y [sinónimos-de-etiquetas](/questions/tagged/sin%c3%b3nimos-de-etiquetas), pero también (si tengo [el privilegio y los puntos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)) podría [sugerir el sinónimo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1192/127) para que se vote. ¿Lo hago en paralelo o espero un tiempo? ¿Cuánto? ¿O espero a que se llegue a un umbral de votos en la discusión en Meta? ¿A cuánto?
- O quizás es una etiqueta para la cual [no hay suficientes usuarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/851/127), y un moderador tiene que intervenir. ¿Cómo y cuándo paso de la discusión en Meta a la solicitud al moderador? ¿Reetiqueto la discusión en Meta, genero una nueva publicación, levanto un reporte, o qué?
- O quizás la etiqueta ni siquiera existe aún, pero creo que es una buena idea crearla como forma de que aparezca cuando se busca, y así evitar un mal uso de otra etiqueta. ¿Qué hago en este caso?
- O quizás es una etiqueta que es más que evidente que es un sinónimo, en la cual la discusión prácticamente no tiene sentido. Tomemos como ejemplo a un extremo: [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net)←[vb-net](/questions/tagged/vb-net). ¿Se tienen que cumplir todos los pasos que con todas las etiquetas? ¿O podríamos esperar que un moderador tome las riendas antes y directamente lo genere? ¿En qué casos lo haría y cuándo?

En definitiva, ¿cuál es el proceso para la creación de sinónimos de etiquetas?
Me interesa que se pueda definir un protocolo que cubra el caso general, pero también los casos límite mencionados.

Comment: @Rubén gracias, agregué los enlaces en la pregunta, donde podían ser pertinentes.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72060/discussion-between-ruben-and-mariano).

Comment: Entiendo la pregunta como: el sistema de votación de sinónimos no funciona, ¿cómo lo gestionamos desde Meta? ¿Es así?

Comment: @fedorqui en parte sí, pero no creo que "no funcione", sino que hay casos específicos para los cuales definir un procedimiento haría que todo funcione mejor, y nos evitaríamos la incertidumbre de no saber cómo proceder (si no se está entendiendo, editen con total libertad)

Comment: Incluso en SO ha habido sinónimos que han tardado años en aceptarse. En mi caso, las veces que se han aceptado ha sido a base de pings en chats y publicaciones, ergo la gente tiende a usar Meta para esta finalidad. Es por ello que me parece muy bueno que sugieras un protocolo para agilizar y objetivar el proceso. Todo me acaba llevando a pensar otra vez en [¿Cómo deberíamos gestionar las propuestas en Meta para que sus respuestas/encuestas tengan efecto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2093/83).

Comment: @fedorqui tal cual. Creo que es más o menos la misma pregunta que la tuya, pero aplicada a un caso específico. Aprovechemos que no somos SO, y que no es tan complicado como allá organizar bien las etiquetas desde el comienzo, atacando el tema antes de que se vuelva un problema mayor, con miles de preguntas

Answer (score -1):

Luego de revisar la ayuda de Stack Overflow en Español, Meta, Meta SO y Meta SE mi conclusión es que el proceso actual es el que se indica abajo, más con fines descriptivos (cómo es) que con fines prescriptivos (cómo debe ser).

---

## Paso 0

Para ser usuario de SOes y hacer uso de su sistema de etiquetas para explorar y buscar en el sitio no hace falta ser miembro por lo que es posible que aún sin contar cuenta identifiques la necesidad de crear un sinónimo, sin embargo, los pasos siguientes son exclusivos para miembros, así que si aún no te registras, deberás hacerlo para poder continuar. Véase [¿Cómo crear una cuenta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/creating-accounts).

## Paso 1

Participa en el sitio y obtén reputación ya que los pasos siguientes requieren de privilegios y estos se obtienen con base en la reputación. Véase [¿Qué es la reputación?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

## Paso 2

### Opción 2.1

Si tienes más de 5 (cinco) y menos de 2,500 (dos mil quinientos) puntos de reputación o 2,500 o más y así lo deseas haz una publicación en Meta.

- Usa la etiqueta [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n) en caso de que no estés del todo seguro o pienses que podría causar alguna polémica.
- Usa la etiqueta [soporte](/questions/tagged/soporte) en caso de estés del todo seguro, que es indiscutible y que se requiere la asistencia de un moderador (otro usuario con la puntuación requerida o un moderador diamantado)

  - Un caso en el que se requeriría la asistencia de un moderador diamantado es en el que aún no haya suficientes usuarios con la puntuación requerida en la etiqueta o bien cuando los hay pero estos no prestan atención a los sinónimos.

En cualquiera de los casos anteriores incluye [sinónimos-de-etiquetas](/questions/tagged/sin%c3%b3nimos-de-etiquetas).

### Opción 2.2

Referencia [¿Crear sinónimos de etiqueta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)

#### Paso 2.2.1

Si tienes 2,500 (dos mil quinientos) o más puntos de reputación y al menos 5 puntos en la etiqueta maestra ve a la página de sinónimos de dicha etiqueta y propón el sinónimo. Los detalles se indican en [Crear sinónimos de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).

#### Paso 2.2.2

**Opción 2.2.2.1**

Los demás usuarios con al menos 5 puntos en la etiqueta maestra tienen la opción de votar los sinónimos propuestos. Una propuesta de sinónimo se aprueba cuando alcanza **4** y se elimina cuando alcanza **-2**.

**Opción 2.2.2.2**

Referencia [¿Quiénes son los moderadores del sitio, y cuál es su cometido?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

Los moderadores del sitio, también llamados moderadores diamantados, entre sus potestades está el aprobar sinónimos de etiqueta.

## Paso 3

### Opción 3.1

Olvídate y pasa a otra cosa

### Opción 3.2

Invita a otros con 5 (cinco) puntos o más en la etiqueta a votar el sinónimo

### Opción 3.3

Si realizaste una publicación en Meta invita a otros a participar.

## Paso 4

Si el sinónimo no se crea por falta de votos / intervención de un moderador diamantado,

### Opción 4.1

Si existe una publicación en Meta, repórtala.

### Opción 4.2

Si no existe una publicación en Meta, créala (véase Opción 2.1)

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo Rubén, pero creo que no fui del todo claro en la pregunta. Sé cuáles son los requisitos para crear un sinónimo, y sé qué se tiene que cumplir para que quede efectivo. Mi pregunta apunta a algo completamente diferente: establecer un protocolo a seguir para cada uno de los pasos que se deberían cumplir, y qué condiciones debería esperar un moderador para crearlo, entre otras. Fijate las preguntas que fui haciendo, que son algunas de las cosas que pretendo revisar. No creo que convenga ver "Opciones", sino más bien un procedimiento a seguir.

Comment: Como referencia, podés tomar a [¿Cuál es el proceso de remover etiquetas (quemarlas)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2839/127)... Por ejemplo, en tu respuesta no se responde qué parámetros tienen que cumplirse en la discusión en Meta antes de proponerlo.. o qué pasos hay que seguir para que un moderador lo genere sin que haya una votación y qué condiciones se deben cumplir... o cuál es el protocolo para una etiqueta que no existe

Answer (score -2):

No estoy seguro de la conveniencia de incluir esto en la pregunta y como no forma parte del "protocolo" que propuse en mi respuesta previa lo agrego acá.

## Casos sin "resolver"

Preguntas con [sinónimos-de-etiquetas](/questions/tagged/sin%c3%b3nimos-de-etiquetas) sin etiqueta de estado

**Era Moderadores Electos**

[[sinónimos-de-etiquetas] created:2017-08-1.. is:question -[estado-*]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsin%C3%B3nimos-de-etiquetas%5D+created%3A2017-08-1..+is%3Aquestion+-%5Bestado-*%5D)

**Era Moderadores Pro Tempore**

[[sinónimos-de-etiquetas] created:..2017-07-31 is:question -[estado-*]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsin%C3%B3nimos-de-etiquetas%5D+created%3A..2017-07-31+is%3Aquestion+-%5Bestado-*%5D)

Preguntas sin [sinónimos-de-etiquetas](/questions/tagged/sin%c3%b3nimos-de-etiquetas)

- [Diferenciar las etiquetas Angular y AngularJS](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1495/65)